# In search of PhpStorm found files are shown with cut path

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Using Find in Path in PhpStorm 2019.2.3 I would like to see the full path of found files. As on the screenshot below, when match is found in different files with similar name, it is very confusing that path is replaced with `/.../`.

Is there is such option?

[image]

Comment: Click the "Open in Find Window" button in the bottom: it can show such info there.

Comment: I know this option. It is not a decision as if I want to check content of some found page I need to open this page in editor(in dialog I can see page content without page openin)

Comment: You CAN preview (and edit) a file there without opening it as well --- just enable that option there.